# Did Jesus transform into spirit form after Resurrection

Tags: life-of-jesus, spirit, resurrection-of-jesus

In the 40 days after the Resurrection and before his Ascension, Jesus appears and disappears to people, including his disciples.

He also is not recognizable by some of his followers including Mary Magdalene at certain occasions until he identifies himself.

Is there any evidence or reason given on how Jesus' human form has now been enhanced with spirit-like powers?

Also - is there any information on whether Jesus stayed with his disciples or his mother during these 40 days, I saw [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6585/999), but I think there isn't any such information?

Comment: As it is worded, this is a truth question, which is out of scope for this site. Please review the [faq] and [about] pages. It would help to indicate which tradition you are looking for answers from (Protestant, Catholic, Mormon, etc.)

Comment: VTC: I think we need some direction here on what perspectives are being sought. (Christian creed or secular history? Baptist or Mormon? Catechism or Protestant Scripture?)

Comment: @Jas3.1 Is there any reason to believe that Christianity would not agree on this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably the most definitive verse on this is in Luke:

> 36 While they were telling these things, He Himself stood in their midst and said to them, “Peace be to you.” 37 But they were startled and frightened and thought that they were seeing a spirit. 38 And He said to them, “Why are you troubled, and why do doubts arise in your hearts?
>
> 39 See My hands and My feet, that it is I Myself; **touch Me** and see, for **a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have.**” 40 And when He had said this, He showed them His hands and His feet. 41 While they still could not believe it because of their joy and amazement, He said to them, “Have you anything here to eat?” 42 They gave Him a piece of a broiled fish; 43 and **He took it and ate it** before them. Luke 24:36-42 NASB

Here Jesus affirms that a spirit does not have flesh and blood, but He Himself does.  To prove it, He tells His disciples to touch Him.  Then He provides another proof by taking a piece of broiled fish and eating it.  This is further proof because spirits do not and cannot eat physical food.

These appear to be just two of the many convincing proofs Luke mentions in the first chapter of Acts:

> To these He also presented Himself alive after His suffering, by many convincing proofs, appearing to them over a period of forty days and speaking of the things concerning the kingdom of God.  Acts 1:3 NASB

So, no, Jesus was not merely a spirit.  His resurrection was a bodily resurrection.  However, just as before the resurrection, He was Lord of Creation and could do miraculous things.

Comment: Incidentally, the heresy of Gnosticism has it's roots in the concept that Jesus didn't physically resurrect, but rather resurrected in Spirit only, leading to their belief that the body is bad, and the spirit is good, and thus it doesn't matter what you do in the body.

Comment: @DavidMorton I think you got that backwards... Gnosticism had its roots in the Platonic dualism of material and spiritual, and applied that to Christianity, thereby concluding that Jesus *could not have* resurrected physically. As a separate application of their beliefs, some took the dualism to "it doesn't matter what you do in the body", but others took it to "you must reject the impulses of the body".

Answer (score 0):

Paul describes what a body of flesh and bone is in Ephesians 5:30.

> For we are members of his body, of his flesh, and of his bones.

This is the kind of body that Jesus resurrected into. This isn't just a spiritual body only, but it also has flesh. The flesh component is from the members of the body that the spirit of Jesus dwells in. The conclusion you reach by taking Paul at his word is the disciples themselves were members of the resurrected body of flesh and bone that the spirit of Jesus dwelt in.

The reason it says He ate "cooked fish" was because the disciples he chose and sent out were to become "fishers of men". This was a symbolic way of saying that Jesus wanted His body of flesh and bone to grow and expand. His resurrection was the assembling of a body of flesh and bone to function as a tabernacle for the spirit of Jesus to live and act through. And, in the process, the members of this body also obtained spiritual life by way of the indwelling of the spirit of Jesus. It is a mutually beneficial symbiosis. They yielded their flesh to the spirit and will of Jesus and Jesus gave His spirit and eternal life to those still in the flesh.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Jesus did not personally have flesh and bones in Luke 24:36-42, at his ascension in verses 50-53, and therefore still?

Comment: @Mike The return of Jesus Christ to live among his people as a resurrected individual person was not to take place until the Gentiles were to be offered his kingdom on the earth.  Jesus said his kingdom is not of this world, meaning he wouldn't rule and reign personally upon the throne of his kingdom until his personal return.  However, his presence as a being of flesh and bone is exactly what the scriptures state.  This is why Jesus considered Saul's persecution of Christians as Saul persecuting the flesh-and-bone body of himself.  They were one with him and count as members of his body.

Comment: I do not disagree with Jesus' intimate connection with the body of believers.  However, the question wonders about Jesus body between resurrection and ascension, prior to Pentecost.  Did Jesus have flesh and bone when he appeared in the locked room?

Comment: @Mike Seems we are revisiting a point of disagreement in the early ecumenical councils.  I myself am in the camp of the "heretics" who believe the resurrection of Jesus as a being of flesh and bone is literally what you call the "intimate connection with the body of believers".  The body of believers is the flesh and bone body of Christ.  The resurrection of Jesus as an individual person comes later when it is time for him to rule and reign on the throne of his kingdom.  He will indwell a new Messiah just as the fullness of the Godhead indwelled him, making him the Messiah.

Answer (score 0):

Why would Jesus go to such length to prove that He resurrected in the flesh? Resurrection in the Spirit would Not have been victory over death...(the penalty of sin) thus meaning that Satan had triumphed .... Jesus then surely died in vain to EXCEMPT man from the death sentence. In Revelation it speaks of the Ancient of days.. A spirit does not age. "See My hands and My feet, that it is **I Myself**; touch Me and see, for a spirit does not have flesh and bones as you see that I have.” And when He had said this, He showed them His hands and His feet. 41 While they still could not believe it because of their joy and amazement, He said to them, “Have you anything here to eat?” They gave Him a piece of a broiled fish; and He took it and ate it before them. Luke 24:36-42 This statement... spoken by Jesus, would thus class Him as a liar.. If this is true then we might as well discard the New Testament. Doubting Thomas was told by Jesus to look for himself the nail prints in his hands.. which he acknowledged.. Spirit would not carry these marks. JjC

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer is okay for this site's guidelines, but that is more a fault with the question. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus Christ is resurrected in flesh, both spirit and flesh for he conquered death and rose from the dead physically. God bless doubtful Thomas who questioned His existence in the flesh, for unless he had seen for himself would he believe providing enough proof for unbelievers or those lacking in faith. I believe in the resurrected power of Jesus Christ that he still lives today and has not died. For he was changed from mortality to imortality, that in itself is enough proof and self explainotory. Conclusion: trust in the LORD with all of thine heart and lean not to thine own understanding. For as Paul said our faith, religion and preaching would be vain if Christ had not risen.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are several instances of beings appearing to humans in the Old Testament and eating food provided by them. So I think your statement that sprits 'do not and cannot eat food' is wrong and, unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Can you support your answer with sources and quotations.